# Parallax not working in Firefox and ie

Tags: jquery, css, parallax, gsap

i cant figurate why my script work only on chrome.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
     TweenLite.to($('body'), 
        .5, 
        { css: 
            {
                'background-position':parseInt(event.pageX/8) + "px "+parseInt(event.pageY/12)+"px, "+parseInt(event.pageX/15)+"px "+parseInt(event.pageY/15)+"px, "+parseInt(event.pageX/30)+"px "+parseInt(event.pageY/30)+"px"
            }
        });
  });
});
```

demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/UW9b6/1/

Answer (score 0):

On problem is here:

```
 $(document).mousemove(function(e){   // passing event data in e
```

Later on you're looking for event data in `event`.

BTW, your fiddle isn't loading `bootstrap` properly, so I can't test this there.